# AlwaysOn Availability Group creation - Is it possible to delay the adding of a secondary replica?

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups

Currently I have a windows failover cluster with a single node only, because the second node will only become available on an production go live date. Prior to this, I was wondering if it would be possible to create the AlwaysOn Availability Group with just the Primary replica. This is in order that I could bring a listener online, in order address various configurations, in order to reduce the tasks required on the go live date. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. You have to specify at least one secondary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but you need to use T-SQL. It is not possible using wizard in ssms.

Here is the link how to configure new AG using T-SQL just skip everything related to secondary replica.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6790/create-always-on-availability-groups-tsql/

Below is the exact scrip that allowed me to create single node AlwaysOn Availability Group. Replace text ">>text<<" with database name, server name, listener name and IP address. Of course you also need to have failover clustering services running etc. This is only SQL part.

```
USE master
GO

CREATE DATABASE [>>DATABASE NAME<<]
GO
 
CREATE ENDPOINT Hadr_endpoint STATE = STARTED   
   AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 5022)   
   FOR DATABASE_MIRRORING (ROLE = ALL); 
GO
 
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::[Hadr_endpoint] TO [NT Service\MSSQLSERVER]
GO
 
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.server_event_sessions WHERE name = 'AlwaysOn_health')
BEGIN
   ALTER EVENT SESSION [AlwaysOn_health] ON SERVER WITH (STARTUP_STATE=ON);
END
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions WHERE name = 'AlwaysOn_health')
BEGIN
   ALTER EVENT SESSION [AlwaysOn_health] ON SERVER STATE=START;
END
GO
 
CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP [>>AG-NAME<<]
WITH (AUTOMATED_BACKUP_PREFERENCE = SECONDARY, DB_FAILOVER = ON, DTC_SUPPORT = NONE)
FOR DATABASE [>>DATABASE NAME<<]
REPLICA ON 
N'>>Primary Server name<<' 
WITH (ENDPOINT_URL = N'TCP://>>Primary Server name<<.domain.com:5022', 
  FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL, 
  AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT, 
  BACKUP_PRIORITY = 25, 
  SEEDING_MODE = MANUAL, 
  SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL)
 );
GO
 
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [>>AG-NAME<<]
ADD LISTENER N'>>Listener name<<' (
WITH IP
((N'>>Listener IP<<', N'255.255.255.0')
)
, PORT=1433);
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however step 6 (Create Availability Group on Primary) requires the identity of a secondary. Which will stop its creation if omitted. Without the AOAG the Listener cannot be defined (and made active in active directory), so I stand with my original answer.

Comment: I’ve alredy created few always on with one node (for non prod purpose) so I'm pretty sure it is possible. Have you changed backup preference and failover mode?

Comment: Tested it today and added T-SQL used to create AG with only one node.